# Sort a list of lists with different sublists length

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to sort a list of lists with different sub-lists length?
I went through some of the links that talks about sorting list of lists; but they all assume the list will have same length of sub-lists.
But, in my case, I would like to know if I can sort the list of variable-length sublists?

For example:

```
    list_of_lists = [ [3, 2], [1, 3, 4], [1, 0, 1, 4], [0] ]
```

After sorting, I should have a new list like

```
 sorted_list = [ [0], [1, 0, 1, 4], [1, 3, 4], [3, 2] ]
```

I can specify multiple keys while sorting, but that works only when the sub-lists are of same length.

Edit:
I did not realize by passing the list to 'sorted' directly will sort the given integer lists in the expected way. Thanks to @jonrsharpe for the pointer.

However, my list contains lists of strings in a specific format.
For ex:

```
list_of_lists  = [
        ['a/s/e/e.c:Show:', 'a/s/e/e.c:INDX:3055'],
        ['a/s/e/e.c:Show:', 'a/s/e/e.c:display:3026','a/s/e/e.c:Struct:2905'],
        ['a/s/e/e.c:Show:', 'a/s/e/e.c:CODE:3056'],
        ['a/s/e/e.c:Show:', 'a/s/e/e.c:display:3026', 'a/s/e/e.c:INDEX:2925'],
        ['a/s/e/e.c:Show:', 'a/s/e/e.c:display:3026', 'a/s/e/e.c:Index:2921'],
        ['a/s/e/e.Show:', 'a/s/e/e.c:display:3026', 'a/s/e/e.c:Name:2917']
]
```

I wanted to sort the above list based on the integer value (if present).

```
Sorted list = [
        ['a/s/e/e.c:Show:', 'a/s/e/e.c:display:3026', 'a/s/e/e.c:Struct:2905'],
        ['a/s/e/e.Show:', 'a/s/e/e.c:display:3026', 'a/s/e/e.c:Name:2917'],
        ['a/s/e/e.c:Show:', 'a/s/e/e.c:display:3026', 'a/s/e/e.c:Index:2921'],
        ['a/s/e/e.c:Show:', 'a/s/e/e.c:display:3026', 'a/s/e/e.c:INDEX:2925'],
        ['a/s/e/e.c:Show:', 'a/s/e/e.c:INDX:3055'],
        ['a/s/e/e.c:Show:', 'a/s/e/e.c:CODE:3056']
]
```

Comment: how do you want the list to be sorted?

Comment: What's the logic you're trying to apply? For that example, `sorted([ [3, 2], [1, 3, 4], [1, 0, 1, 4], [0] ])` works without any help.

Comment: @KevinYobeth I wanted them to be sorted based on a integer value in the respective position (starting from index 0).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am sorry I missed to mention some details in the question as I did not realize simple integer sub-lists will work straight-away with sorted as you mentioned.

In my case, the list does not contain the lists of integers; rather a string in the below format.

list_of_lists = [ ['a'], ['abc:10', 'def:20'], ['abc:1', 'def:30', 'ab:2'], ['abc:0'] ]

This should be sorted based on the integer value on the sublist items.
Sorted_ist = [ ['a'], ['abc:0'], ['abc:1', 'def:30', 'ab:2'] , ['abc:10', 'def:20'] ]

Comment: Then [edit] the question. But basically the answer is to write a `key` function that gives something that sorts the way you want, see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html. In your case maybe `['a']` -> `[]` and `['abc:10', 'def:20']` -> `[10, 20]`? Then split that task down into smaller ones and solve each of them, it's too specific to your use case to be useful to SO.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check now. I just wanted to know if we can specify the 'key' element in the sort for the list that does have variable-sized lists. And we may not know the size of the each lists as well. However, from your answer, it looks like I need to break it down into multiple lists of simple integers and then apply sort.

Comment: You need a key function that does something like `['a/s/e/e.c:Show:', 'a/s/e/e.c:display:3026', 'a/s/e/e.c:Struct:2905']` -> `[None, 3026, 2905]`, yes.